# Google Sheet Array formula Column result multiplication by cell value

Tags: google-sheets

=ArrayFormula({QUERY({'2020 BBVA IRHP'!A:O,'2020 BBVA IRHP'!D:D&"-"&'2020 BBVA IRHP'!D:D},"SELECT 'IRHP','BBVA','IRHP BVA','EUR',Col15,Col1,Col6,Col7,Col16,Col6*$T$1$ WHERE Col1 CONTAINS '2021'")})

I want to multiple the result of Col6 by an FX rate contained in the Sheet in Cell T1 .

What is the syntax in the formula to refer to cell T1 to make this work ?

Comment: Post some sample data or share a sample google-sheet here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The query statement is just a text string. You can modify it by cell values using string concatenation and manipulation.

To multiply every number in `query()` column 6 with the same multiplier that is stored in a spreadsheet cell, use this pattern:

`...Col6 * " & T1 & " where...`